# What are kviews?

Tags: discussion

When reviewing questions, there is indication of the number of **views** for a particular question.  In some cases it is listed as **kviews** instead of **views**.  What are **kviews**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1000's of views. (Kilo-views).

Comment: Is there a Mega-views? :)

Comment: @Alvar, even if I say yes, I cannot confirm it. The oldest site, stackoverflow, has a question with 861k views, followed by 302k. [search query](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A300000)

Comment: By the way, the [What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/184618/427545) is hilarious!

Comment: That's A W E S O M E ! ! ! ! ! :)

Comment: Wouldn't it make more since to place the K next to the number? 2K views instead of 2 kviews?

Comment: There are Mviews now.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered

Comment: Haha. I always thought it was for Kubuntu specific questions. Stupid :-)